# How can I implement nested boost::mpl::fold

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

How can I implement nested boost::mpl::fold ?

```
namespace mpl=boost::mpl;

typedef mpl::vector_c<int,1,1,1> vec1;
typedef mpl::vector_c<int,2,2,2> vec2;
typedef mpl::vector_c<int,3,3,3> vec3;
typedef mpl::vector<vec1,vec2,vec3> vvec;

typedef typename mpl::lambda
    <mpl::fold
        <mpl::_1
        ,mpl::int_<0>
        ,typename mpl::lambda<mpl::plus<mpl::_1,mpl::_2>>::type
        >
    >::type lam;

typedef typename mpl::fold
    <vvec
    ,mpl::int_<0>
    ,mpl::plus<mpl::_1,typename lam::template apply<mpl::_2>::type>
    >::type result;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((mpl::equal_to<result,mpl::int_<18>>));
```

I want result to be 18, but above equals to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested binds always invite collisions between placeholders: the lambda uses the same placeholders as the outer fold does, and the substitution will do the wrong thing.

Boost Lambda, Boost Bind and yes, even Boost Mpl implement the `protect`/`unprotect` combo so you can fix this:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c20c31ac0cd925aa)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/protect.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal_to.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

typedef mpl::vector_c<int, 1, 1, 1> vec1;
typedef mpl::vector_c<int, 2, 2, 2> vec2;
typedef mpl::vector_c<int, 3, 3, 3> vec3;
typedef mpl::vector<vec1, vec2, vec3> vvec;

typedef typename mpl::lambda<
        mpl::fold<
            mpl::_1, 
            mpl::int_<0>, 
            typename mpl::lambda<mpl::plus<mpl::_1, mpl::_2> >::type
        >
    >::type lam;

typedef typename mpl::fold<
        vvec, 
        mpl::int_<0>, 
        mpl::plus<mpl::_1, mpl::protect<lam>::type::apply<mpl::_2> >
    >::type result;

static_assert(mpl::equal_to<result, mpl::int_<18>>::value, "should be 18");

int main() {}
```